# Use FPGA to program external memory?

Tags: fpga, flash, eeprom

For a project, I am going to use an FPGA to process an incoming data stream and convert it into binary code that a microcontroller runs.

My current idea is to store the processed data on an EEPROM which the microcontroller accesses to run.

- I'm not entirely sure though how to program an EEPROM with an FPGA, or if it's even possible?

I don't have a need to erase every bit individually, and it would be quite a bit easier to just use an ARM chip with XIP, so can I program a SPI/QSPI serial NAND instead? I'm pretty new to FPGA's, but it is crucial for this that I use one since my major requirement is that no flash memory is used to convert the data stream, which rules out another microcontroller (I know the FPGA uses a little memory but since it's just to model the circuit I'm allowing it).

Comment: why not use RAM?

Comment: Why don't you think it's possible to program an EEPROM with an FPGA?  I think it's a lot easier to program an EEPROM than a Flash memory, and people program (write to) Flashes all the time with FPGAs.

Comment: I think you’ll find you can’t use serial NAND for XIP. Serial NOR is the choice here. The fpga is just a big box of lego bricks - you arrange them how you want so if a microcontroller can do something, you can easily create a microcontroller in your fpga or create a specific machine to do exactly what you want.  I really can’t grasp what you’re wanting to achieve and it sounds like an X/Y problem - you’re trying to fit a given solution to the wrong problem.

Comment: FYI: One standard (probably the most common) process for configuring an FPGA is to configure the FPGA through the PC to program an external ROM memory send it the bitstream it will normally to be running. How big is this processed data? And is it processed in real-time?

Comment: After sending the microcontroller's program, do you want to be able to power cycle (switch off and on again) and the microcontroller to still have its code? If not, a RAM instead of a non-volatile memory as program memory for the microcontroller is probably the best solution. Anyway, an EEPROM is accessed just the same way as a RAM; Flash-ROMs are just a bit more complex due to their "command sequences".

Comment: Can you tell us something about your microcontroller and the EEPROM you want to use? Also, things that are sold as "EEPROM" are usually so small that your FPGA could probably just keep the same data in block RAM and act as if it was an EEPROM towards the microcontroller. What's the reason for the very surprising approach of letting an FPGA generate machine code, instead of just storing some data in an external memory that a fixed microcontroller firmware just reads? Since the memory would be the same, there's no speed or design advantage I could see here!

Comment: This depends entirely on the EEPROM, and the FPGA is almost irrelevant. Step 1: Find out how to program the EEPROM. Step 2: Find out whether the FPGA can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your MCU already knows how to boot from external memory… like some ARMs with XIP. That would the difficult thing.

Conceptually, it's quite easy. In your FPGA, you need to implement an interface (probably SPI) with your flash (NOR or hyper or whatever). And then a state machine to drive the SPI port thru the steps needed for the erase/program/verify. After that release SPI control (3-state SCLK/MOSI/CS) and let the MCU run.

Not trivial but it's the bread and butter of FPGA state machine design.